# Place multiple values returned by FILTER into a single cell instead of multiuple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I'm using the FILTER function to return a short list of items from a separate sheet.

This is my current formula in B2:

```
=FILTER('In Care'!D2:D999, A2='In Care'!J2:J999)
```

The results spill into the rows below the formula as long as they are empty or return an error if there are not enough empty rows below the formula to accommodate all the results:

> ```
> #REF!
> Array result was not expanded
> because it would overwrite data in [A1].
> ```

I've been leaving empty rows below each formula to accommodate results however the number of values returned varies and I don't want to leave unnecessary empty rows between the formulas.

What I'd like to do instead of returning multiple rows, is to return a single cell with multiple lines.  In this way, I can have formulas stacked one row after the other without leaving empty rows in between to accommodate their results.

How do I do this?

##### Current Results

|  | A | B |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Lookup Value** | **Formulas** |  |
| **2** | Val_01 | Result_1 | **`← Formula`** |
| **3** |  | Result_2 |  |
| **4** |  | Result_3 |  |
| **5** |  |  | ← *Not Needed* |
| **6** |  |  | ← *Not Needed* |
| **7** | Val_02 | Result_1 | **`← Formula`** |
| **8** |  | Result_2 |  |
| **9** |  | Result_3 |  |
| **10** |  | Result_4 |  |
| **11** |  |  | ← *Not Needed* |

##### Desired Results

|  | A | B |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Lookup Value** | **Formulas** |  |
| **2** | Val_01 | Result_1 Result_2 Result_3 | **`← Formula`** |
| **3** | Val_02 | Result_1 Result_2 Result_3 Result_4 | **`← Formula`** |

Comment: Your edit clarifies things well, and improves the question. Thank you. I now know a bit more about SO markdown, too. :)

Comment: Exactly how I learn everything too 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use the TEXTJOIN Function

[BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en)  [CHAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en)  [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)  [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en)  [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)  [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)

---

## Formulas

1. **Single Row** versions:

   - must be pasted individually into each new row of Column A (1 formula for each row with a value)
   - must have absolute references to row numbers in **`'In Care'`** to stop them from changing when you move the formula between rows.
2. **Multi-Row** versions:

   - need only be entered once and will dynamically accept new lookup values added to Column A as well as any changes made to the data in sheet **`'In Care'`** Columns D and J.
   - range references can be relative as the formula does not move rows.
3. Both versions have been broken out into multiple rows for legibility. You can convert them to a single line by removing the breaks and spaces if you prefer.

#### 1. Comma Delimited

If you prefer a space after each comma use **`", "`** instead of **`","`**

```
# Single Row 
=IFNA(
   TEXTJOIN(",", 1,
     FILTER('In Care'!D$2:D, 'In Care'!J$2:J=A2)))

# Multi-Row Formula
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r,  
   IFNA(
     TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
       FILTER('In Care'!D2:D, 'In Care'!J2:J=r)))))
```

#### 2. Line Break Delimited

```
# Single Row Formula 
=IFNA(
   TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1,
     FILTER('In Care'!D$2:D, 'In Care'!J$2:J=A2)))  

# Multi-Row Formula
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r,  
   IFNA(
     TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, 
       FILTER('In Care'!D2:D, 'In Care'!J2:J=r)))))
```

#### 3. Transpose Values to Rows

This alternative transposes the results so they stack.

```
# Single Row Formula 
=IFNA(
   TOROW( 
     FILTER('In Care'!D$2:D, 'In Care'!J$2:J=A2))) 

# Multi-Row Formula
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, IF(LEN(r), 
   IFNA(
     TOROW( 
       FILTER('In Care'!D$2:D, 'In Care'!J$2:J=r))),)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is *almost* working for me. I tried your first solution, with commas, and I get the 1 cell I want .. plus rows of commas until end of the sheet (or a #REF telling me I need more space). If I add another condition to the FILTER, like `'In Care'!J2:J<>""`I get `#N/A` to the end of the document, telling me that no matches are found. Am I doing something obviously wrong? Should I make a minimal example and add it to my question?

Comment: Sorry hadn't finished. Added handling for no matches and empty rows in column A. Try it now.

Comment: Try [textjoin()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992).

Comment: @doubleunary of course doh! Updated. Thank you! (as usual!)

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the multiple options!